# Why does Powershell inline VersionInfo on Write-Output delivers a different output?

Tags: windows, powershell

I build the following script for debugging:

```
# Store file in var
$File = (Get-ChildItem -Path [ANY_EXE].exe)

# Get VerionInfo
$Version = $File.VersionInfo

# Print VersionInfo
Write-Output "$Version"
```

which results in this output:

```
File:             [ANY_EXE].exe
InternalName:     [ANY_EXE]
OriginalFilename: [ANY_EXE]
FileVersion:      8.20.1.14183
FileDescription:  [DESCRIPTION_FOR_EXE]
Product:          [PRODUCT_FOR_EXE]
ProductVersion:   8.20
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         Englisch (Vereinigte Staaten)
```

Putting the script in this inline function:

```
Write-Output (Get-ChildItem [ANY_EXE].exe).VersionInfo
```

results in a completely different output:

```
ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName                                                                                  
--------------   -----------      --------                                                                                  
8.20             8.20.1.14183     [ANY_EXE].exe
```

How can I get the first output, using an inline function?

Comment: Difference is that you embed the first one in a string. `(Get-ChildItem [ANY_EXE].exe).VersionInfo -as [string]` should give you the same output (`Write-Output` is not actually required, results of any unassigned value expression will be output by default)

Comment: `"$VersionInfo"` forces conversion to a string for interpolation purposes and is thus quite different from `$VersionInfo`. It's not clear from the question if you really want the first or the second variation, but that's the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code fixes my issue:

```
(Get-ChildItem [ANY_EXE]exe).VersionInfo -as [string]
```

Thanks to [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) and [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)
 for explaining the reason and solving my issue.